# Why doesn't the CSS animate when I change the class with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm using the Animate.css from Daniel Eden which I downloaded from [here](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). I can animate things on my website by just using the `animated (typeOfAnimation)` class on the item I want to animate.

Here is my `HTML`:

```
<button onmouseover = "makeEnglishPulse()" id = "english" class = "animated bounceInRight">// English</button>
```

And here is my `JavaScript`:

```
function makeEnglishPulse() {
    document.getElementById("english").class = "animated pulse";
}
```

My button does bounce in once I load my website, but why doesn't it pulse when I go over with the mouse even though I am changing the class?

For any solutions, I'd like to stay `JavaScript` or `HTML` only please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property to set is `.className`, not `.class`.

```
function makeEnglishPulse() {
    document.getElementById("english").className = "animated pulse";
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I can't believe I didn't figure that out.

Comment: @TheMan well it's not exactly obvious :)  The word "class" has been a reserved word in JavaScript since forever, so using an alternative was necessary.